# Need Help creating class hierarchy in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, model-view-controller, design-patterns, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy of data that i would like to build using classes instead of hard coding it in. The structure is like so:

1. Unit (has name, abbreviation, subsystems[5 different types of subsystems])
2. Subsystem ( has type, block diagram(photo), ParameterModel[20 different sets of parameterModels])
3. ParameterModel (30 or so parameters that will have [parameter name, value, units, and model index])

I'm not sure how to do this using classes but what i have made kindof work so far is creating nested dictionaries.

{'Unit':{'Unit1':{'Subsystem':{'Generator':{Parameter:{'Name': param1, 'Value':1, 'Units': 'seconds'}

like this but with 10-15 units and 5-6 subsystems and 30 or so parameters per  subsystem. I know using dictionaries is not the best way to go about it but i cannot figure out the class sharing structure or where to start on building the class structure.

I want to be able to create, read, update and delete, parameters in a tkinter gui that i have built as well as export/import these system parameters and do calculations on them. I can handle the calculations and the import export but i need to create classes that will build out this structure and be able to reference each individual unit/subsystem/parameter/value/etc

I know thats alot but any advice? ive been looking into the factory and abstract factory patterns in hope to try and figure out how to create the code structure but to no avail. I have experience with matlab, visual basic, c++, and various arduio projects so i know most basic programming but this inheritance class structure is something i cannot figure out how to do in an abstract way without hardcoding each parameter with giant names like Unit1_Generator_parameterName_parameter = ____  and i really dont want to do that.

Thanks,
-A

EDIT: Here is one way I've done the implementation using a dictionary but i would like to do this using a class that can take a list and make a bunch of empty attributes and have those be editable/callable generally like setParamValue(unit, susystem, param)  where i can pass the unit the subsystem and then the parameter such as 'Td' and then be able to change the value of the key,value pair within this hierarchy.

```
def create_keys(list):
dict = {key: None for key in list}
return dict


unit_list = ['FL','ES','NN','SF','CC','HD','ND','TH'] #unit abbreviation
sub_list = ['Gen','Gov','Exc','PSS','Rel','BlkD']
params_GENROU = ["T'do","T''do","T'qo","T''qo",'H','D','Xd','Xq',"Xd'","Xq'","X''d=X''q",'Xl','S(1.0)','S(1.2)','Ra']   #parameter names

dict = create_keys(unit_list)

for key in dict:
    dict[key] = create_keys(sub_list)
    dict[key]['Gen'] = create_keys(params_GENROU)
```

and inside each dict[unit][Gen][ParamNames] there should be a dict containing Value, units(seconds,degrees,etc), description and CON(#basically in index for another program we use)

Comment: Have you tried implementing anything yourself? If yes - could you please share your code?

Comment: yes ive went a bunch of different ways but cannot get anything to work entirely. ill edit main post with a couple of my trys.